# Using TRY/CATCH to test for valid mysql server connection

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

MVC3, VB.NET, using EF. I am working on coding up a simple function to handle checking for a valid MySQL connection. If the connection fails the test it will use the secondary server connection. This is required because our hosting provider does not provide failover or redundant MySQL servers. The problem is I tried to use a simple try catch method in the HomeController. This fails early because the Entity Framework is looking the connection that was set up when I set it up... Is there anyway to control that connection dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [set the connection string at runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/234677/Set-the-connection-string-for-Entity-Framework-at).